# how to hidden the hidden files on my MAC(Maverics)?

Tags: macos, operating-system, hidden-files

first, i can't view the hidden files.
so,In according to data of google search, i solved by below command.

> defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE

now, i want to hidden the file again.
but, any commands don't work.. :(

> defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
>   defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool FALSE
>   defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles NO
>   defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles -NO

what is problem??
i tried to relaunch of finder, logout, reboot...

please, guide the method.
thanks.

Comment: oops,, i solved...
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3969143?start=15&tstart=0
comment by X423424X 
the value is 0 .. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The other way is there.

Open terminal = spotlight search terminal

paste in these lines

defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE

killall Finder

To hide hidden files just change TRUE = FALSE

Hope this will work for you, else you can find apps that will [show hidden files mac](http://www.showhiddenfilesmac.com).